# USB-C MST not working

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I'm using this USB-C Multipurpose-Hub:

https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07HMSW9LB/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I've got a Monitor connected to the VGA Port and another on on the HDMI-Port using an HDMI to VGA Converter. Both Monitors work, I extended the Screen from the Internal Laptop Screen, but I can only mirror both external monitors, there are no other options in the monitor menu, when I try to identify them both are marked as '2'.

`xrandr --listmonitors` gives

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/309x1080/174+1280+0  eDP-1
 1: +DP-2 1280/376x1024/301+0+0  DP-2
```

Im using a Lenovo T480. Audio over the HDMI to VGA adapter behind the USB-C hub is working. On Windows I managed to have everything working as expected. Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Things start to get interesting. Ubuntu wanted a firmware update for my mainboard, I did it and some really dirty update process started including reflashing the internal microcontroller. Nothing changed in Ubuntu, but now MST in Windows is broken, too. I did a reflash using Lenovo System Update in Windows, now MST is working here again, but still no MST in Ubuntu.